# inputRichText is not rendering IceFaces 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, rich-text-editor

With icefaces 2 my application is not rendering the richInputText. When I inspect this with firebug it says that it cant find resources

[image]

Do you know what it could be causing this behaviour??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a extra mapping to the web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that its failing to find the images to render the icons for the rich text editor.

If you are using the standard ICEfaces libraries, these are included in the css resources, so check you've imported the ICEfaces css resources completely.